# Yii returns NULL for added db column value

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I installed user module in my Yii app. After that, I wanted to add aditional 'level' column / field to my user model, so I simply added the column directly to my databasein phpMyadmin, and edited a bit User model in user module.

However, when I try to load user data, regardless of what is the value of the field for 
certain model/user, yii, always returns NULL for that field.

This is the export SQL from my database for the column & row I tried to load:

```
`aclevel` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
```

and

```
(my_id, 'myusername', '', 'myemail@gmail.com', 'whatever', whatever, whatever, 0, '2013-08-15 08:43:02', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

where 0 is the value for the column/field in question. However, I tried also to save value 3 and yii also returned NULL.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you added the `level` field in the User model? Try adding it as a  safe attribute... If still not working show some User model code...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been an issue of adding the added field to defaultScope array/function in my User model.